# Can't get ID of clicked link

Tags: jquery

Maybe I'm being crazy, but I can't get the ID of the `<a>` link that is being clicked. The `var` for security works fine, and there is definatly content in the ID attribute. I'm I missing something?

Here is the PHP -

```
<span id="<?php echo $load_post_content_nonce; ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="read-more" target="_blank">Read more...</a>
</span>
```

Here is the JS -

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('a.read-more').live('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var security = $(this).parent('span').attr('id');

    });

});
```

Here is the HTML output from one of the links -

```
<span id="b494a85e81">
    <a id="6623" class="read-more" href="http://test.dynedrewett.com/warring-parents-told-to-face-up-not-fall-out-over-contact-with-children/">Read more...</a>
</span>
```

Comment: what is the html output of your  php code

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/F2wQx/. Are you sure it has a value?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that gets generated by the PHP code?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - Yep, certain. I even added the `$load_post_content_nonce` value to it to be sure, as that is being picked up, but still nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine as well: http://jsfiddle.net/SvHSx/. Possibly PHP generates text with double `"` quotes, so that the markup becomes invald?

Comment: Use of the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks.

Comment: HTML Output now added to question.

Comment: @A.K - The link that is click is porduced by AXAJ, so `.live()` is necessary as far as I am aware. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `.live()` is **deprecated** as of jQuery 1.7. Even in older versions, `.delegate()` is now the preferred method for handling delegated events. For later versions, `on()` is the correct method for handling delegated events, as explained in the [jQuery docs for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which explains how to port to `.on()`.

This *does* work for content generated dynamically after DOM ready with AJAX or some other method, but you have to use the correct syntax. For handling clicks on dynamically generated `.read-more` links, do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', 'a.read-more', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = this.id;
        var security = $(this).parent('span').attr('id');
    });
});
```

---

In `$(document).on('click', 'a.read-more', function(e) {...})`, you can replace `document` with any *static* parent element (one which exists at the time the handler is bound, and which is guaranteed to exist 'forever', in order to handle clicks on future `.read-more` links; the documentation explains the usage in depth.

*As of the time of this writing*, the jQuery object [does ***not*** have a property named `id`](http://api.jquery.com/category/properties/); to access an element's ID you must either: 
- Use `.attr( 'id' )` 
or 
- Use the native DOM element's `id` property: `$(element)[0].id` or `element.id`

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('a.read-more').live('click', function(e)
      {
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = this.id;
          var security = $(this).parent('span').id;
       }); 
    });
```

you will find id by this.id.

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated, but `.on()` doesn't seem to work with AJAX generated content.

Comment: @DavidGard .on() function was only included in jQuery 1.7 it won’t work with earlier versions

Comment: @ShahzadImam - I inclue the latest version of jQuery (src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"), which I believe is currently 1.7.1, so I have `.on()` available to me, but it doesn't do the same job as `.live()`. Whether that is deliberate or not I don't know, I've not had time to fully digest the docs yet.

Answer (score 2):

Php is generating the code wrong, this script must work.

Also, try converting from "live" to "on", because:

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(),
>   .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see
>   .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes
>   itself, see .one()

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: If he's using an old version on jQuery .on doesn't work. You need to be sure what kind of jQuery version he's using before suggest this.

Comment: I suppose he can figure out this from this part of my quoted text: **As of jQuery 1.7**

Comment: `.on` does work in my version (1.7.1), but as the link that is being clicked is generated by AJAX, it's not detecting the click, so that is why I was uing `.live()`. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) **does** work with content generated by AJAX -- that's the whole reason it has replaced `.live()` and `.live()` has been deprecated. It has a slightly different syntax than the normal usage, see my answer for the correct use.

Comment: @nbrooks - You are quite right, `.on()` does work with AJAX generated content. Earlier I tried it as `$('a.read-more').on('click', function(e)...` and that was not working (although now seems to be also - head -> brick wall -> repeat!), so I obviously had an error (although Firebug didn't spot it). Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.

For just `ID` you can also do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('a.read-more').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var id = this.id;
        var security = this.parent('span').id;

    });

});
```

without using `.attr()`.

The error is for sure in your **`PHP` code**.

Comment: `.attr()` is a good approach. See the difference http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/8xLmB/ By using `.attr()` it alerts the `6623` but without using `.attr()` it alerts `undefined`

Comment: I know that is deprecated, but he used it and don't know what version of jQuery he's using.

Comment: This answer is *totally* incorrect. Since when can you do `$(this).id`?

Comment: Don't know why or how, but this worked! Thanks for the tip, will try and remember for future random problmes!

Comment: the first that I found for @Matt: [http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/03/31/jquery-get-the-id-of-the-current-element/](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/03/31/jquery-get-the-id-of-the-current-element/)

Comment: replace `$(this).id` with `this.id`

Comment: @Matt [http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/Xn8LL/](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/Xn8LL/)

Comment: @AndreaTurri: I don't see what you're trying to prove in that fiddle, apart from my original statement was correct. Notice you're doing `this.id` rather than `$(this).id`, which is valid as you're operating on the HTMLElement rather than the jQuery object. You'll also note that your `security` variable is undefined, as you're trying to retrieve the `id` property from the `jQuery` object, which is undefined (and is the same as trying to retrieve `id` from `$(this)`).

Comment: That is not how you would handle a delegated event using `.on()`. The syntax doesn't translate directly from `.live()`. See the documentation for how to implement that functionality correctly.